# Passing values into a strongly typed MVC 2 view?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, view, model, controller

all.

I am relatively new to Microsoft's new implementation of Model View Controller. I'm creating an app in MVC 2.

I have a strongly typed view called "CreateAlbum" that's tied to a model class called "Album". All information displayed in that view comes from the "Album" model. I need to display data from two lists (that aren't in the "Album" model) inside my "CreateAlbum" view.

The contents of these two lists were created in an Action method called "CreateAlbum()".

- How do I pass two lists which were created in an action method to a strongly typed view?
- Once I pass those two lists into a strongly typed view, I'd need to tie information in each of those lists to a drop-down list. How would I do that?

Again, please note that this is MVC 2. Answers that I've seen are all specific to MVC 3. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could define gets for your lists and when the ui loads  bind them to the appropriate controller action. Or you could create an Create Album function returning a model including the two list  you defined above.

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution would be to create an AlbumViewModel class that will hold the Album model as a property and two functions to populate the lists, no need for another action method.

your view CreateAlbum will get AlbumViewModel as it's model, and in the [post] action for CreateAlbum specify a Bind Prefix so you will have an album in the controller action:

```
public ActionResult CreateAlbum([Bind(Prefix = "AlbumData")] Album)
```